# Correct way to open another ListFragment from onListItemClick or implement subcategories in ListFragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I'm trying to implement subcategories via ListFragments and I'm having an issue with the previous fragment list not being cleared and onbackpress the parent list fragment not showing up.

Example this is my Parent ListFragment:

```
package com.best.photo.now;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.best.photo.now.R;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

public class CategoryListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private static final String TAG = CategoryListFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context mContext = null;
    private String[] mCategories = null;

    private CategoryListAdapter mAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //send screen name to google
        Tracker t = ((WallpaperApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker();
        t.setScreenName(MainActivity.CATEGORY);
        t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity()).dispatchLocalHits();

        mContext = getActivity();
        mCategories = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_list);

        mAdapter = new CategoryListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        System.out.println("Position onClick: "+position);


        if(position==2)
        {
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new AbstractListFragment());

            ft.commit();


        }
        else
        {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
           ((OnCategoryListItemClickListern)getActivity()).onCategoryListItemClick(v);
        }

    }


    private class CategoryListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mCategories.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mCategories[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(view == null) 
                view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.category_list_item, null);
            ((TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.category_name))).setText(mCategories[position]);
            ((ImageView)(view.findViewById(R.id.category_image))).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            view.setTag(mCategories[position]);


        return view;    
        }

    }


    public static interface  OnCategoryListItemClickListern{
        public  abstract void onCategoryListItemClick(View v);



    }
}
```

And the list is 
All Categories
Favorites
Abstract
Animals

so on...

And on onListItemClick, the next fragment is opened

which is same as the first fragment except it's onListItemClick has the parents Click Listener.

```
package com.best.photo.now;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.best.photo.now.R;
import com.best.photo.now.CategoryListFragment.OnCategoryListItemClickListern;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

public class AbstractListFragment extends ListFragment {
    private static final String TAG = AbstractListFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private Context mContext = null;
    private String[] mAbstract = null;
    private AbstractListAdapter mAdapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //send screen name to google
        Tracker t = ((WallpaperApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker();
        t.setScreenName(MainActivity.CATEGORY);
        t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(getActivity()).dispatchLocalHits();

        mContext = getActivity();

        mAbstract = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.abstract_list);

        mAdapter = new AbstractListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);


    }


    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

         ((OnCategoryListItemClickListern)getActivity()).onCategoryListItemClick(v);



    }


    private class AbstractListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mAbstract.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mAbstract[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(view == null) 
                view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.abstract_list_item, null);
            ((TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.abstract_name))).setText(mAbstract[position]);
            ((ImageView)(view.findViewById(R.id.abstract_image))).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            view.setTag(mAbstract[position]);


        return view;    
        }

    }


    public static interface  OnAbstractListItemClickListern{
        public  abstract void onAbstractListItemClick(View v);



    }


}
```

On click of any item from the list, search api from flickr is queried and related results are fetched. Which works fine, but the 2nd fragment list is not cleared and shows in the background of the image results.

Also, on backpress I'm unable to reach to the parent listfragment.

I tried using addToBackStack(null) while calling the 2nd fragment but it didnt work for me.

What am I missing here?

Also, is there any other way to achieve subcategories for ListFragments instead of creating multiple ListFragments class/layouts for each subcategory types?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Thanks,
Arnab

Comment: I used this in the child fragment
`ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, new AllCategoryListFragment());
ft.addToBackStack(null); 
ft.hide(current);
ft.commit();`

and in the child fragment
' 
setView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(); 
 
'

and i'm the overwriting issue gets resolved. But now when go back, instead of taking me to the subcategory->maincategories. it directly takes me to the main category list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replace try calling add function:

```
ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, new AbstractListFragment());
ft.addToBackStack(null); 
ft.commit();
```

Comment: Hey @vipul 
This works for the back issue. But it overwrites the new fragment list on top of the parent list fragment.

any solution for this issue?